# looping through a numpy array summing stuff to another array

Tags: python, loops, numpy

im trying to loop through an nd numpy array and having trouble

the first part of the code below just makes a co-ordinate system and random numbers

```
import numpy as np
import math
N = 100
h, i = np.linspace(-20., 20., N), np.linspace(-20., 20., N)
xh, yi = np.meshgrid(h, i) 
E1= np.empty_like(xh)   
E2= np.empty_like(yi)   
Et = np.empty_like(xh)
poo=10 
ppp = [5]*poo
A=np.linspace(10, 50,poo)
B=np.linspace(-30, 10,poo)
C=np.linspace(-10, 20,poo)
D=[]
AAA=[]
for i in range(len(A)):
    D=(A[i],B[i],C[i])      
    AAA.append(D)   

#everything above this is fine
```

below this i want to have  the equation AAA0-AAA1+AAA2 = E1
there are 10 different D's, each D has 3 components. all of the D's combined = AAA

```
for i in range(poo):      
    for j in range(poo):
        x, y = xh[i,j], yi[i,j]
        for k in range(len(AAA)):
            E1[i,j] += AAA[k][0]-AAA[k][1]+AAA[k][2]
            E2[i,j] += AAA[k][0]-AAA[k][1]*AAA[k][2]
    Et[i,j] = (E1[i,j]**2+E2[i,j]**2)**(0.5)
print(Et)
```

the results i get are like this. it seems E1 for each co-ordinate is being summed up over just 1 co-ordinate and E2 is doing the same.

how can i make E1 loopp through all AAA's for the first co-ordniate, then through all the AAA's for the secondf co-ordinate etc....

```
[[  1.19876022e-311   1.19880258e-311   0.00000000e+000 ...,
    0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000 ...,
    0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000 ...,
    0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000]
 ..., 
 [  0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000 ...,
    0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000 ...,
    0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000]
 [  0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000 ...,
    0.00000000e+000   0.00000000e+000
```

i just want it to loop through properly rather than putting everything in first few values

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: something like [4,8,7,6,8,,8...... not [999,.999, 0,0,0,0....

Comment: What are the type and shape of the desired output?

Comment: it should just kind of fill up E1 and E2. they already have a shape

Comment: `for k in range(len(D)):` looks wrong to me. Leaving questions of style to one side wouldn't you want the length of `AAA` here?

Comment: yeah sorry that was a typo it should be that,ive changed it now.  but i still get the same issue

Comment: Et[i,j] = (E1[i,j]**2+E2[i,j]**2)**(0.5) needs to be indented by one. otherwise it will only update after each j loop is completed.

Comment: thanks, still doesnt change anything :/ am i just screwed?

Comment: Again, I don't understand what it is you actually want? Et has shape 100x100 (=10000 elements), your loop replaces a total of  poo * poo = 10*10 = 100 elements in Et.

Comment: `...loopp through all AAA's for the first co-ordinate`  - first coordinate of what? It really isnt clear what your desired result is.  Looks like you are putting the same value in every `E1[i,j]` (and `E2`) but haven't explaned what you want to happen.  Maybe create a [mcve] with a smaller `N` and `poo`, then walk through your process on paper and show us what you expect to see for `E1`, `E2`, and `Et`.

Comment: even still, it should fill 100 values not 2 :(

Comment: In your last loop, what is the purpose of `x` and `y`???

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat - NAA**

You have too many apparent problems and you haven't adequately explained what you want it to do.

In your example, `E1` and `E2` shapes are (100,100)  and `poo` is `10`

```
for i in range(poo):      
    for j in range(poo):
        ...
        E1[i,j] ...
        ...
```

This loop only covers the *top-left* (10,10) *corner* of `E1` and `E2` - `Ex[:10, :10]`.

To cover the entire space, try

```
for i in range(N):      
    for j in range(N):
```

But it looks like you have other problems.

```
E1[i,j] += AAA[k][0]-AAA[k][1]+AAA[k][2]
```

Effectively means

```
E1[i,j] = (AAA[k][0]-AAA[k][1]+AAA[k][2]) ** (N*N)  #if using range(N) in the loops
```

Which makes very large numbers.